# Print PHP string with quotes

Tags: php, html, sql, string, escaping

So I am trying to echo comments that are stored in an SQL database.  Some of these comments contain apostrophes.  So when it prints comments that contain apostrophes it comes out looking like:

```
  echo "<h4>$tip</h4>"

  example: This is Tanner\'s comment.
```

My question is how do I get rid of that backslash before the apostrophe.  I'm sure this is a simple fix but I just can't seem to find it after searching for a while.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1- show the code where you echo the value. 2- Check if the value in the database isn't already escaped...

Comment: Also show the code where you insert a comment into the database. You might be escaping there, where instead you should be preparing and executing your queries.

Comment: You could use something like this: `$text = str_replace("\\'", "'", $text);`, but that would be just like disabling error reporting and saying everything is fine. Go after the real cause...

Comment: It is not escaped in the database. When enter the comment into the database show I use a function to escape would that be easier?

Comment: we would need to see the code used to add the data to the db and the code used to extract and display it in order to be able to help you properly

Comment: I added an answer to the method I used to solve my problem my question. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can use stripslashes function

```
$var = stripslashes(string);
```

This function removes the slashes from a string

Comment: he has slashes he wants to remove so a function called **add**slashes is probably not what  the OP needs

Comment: My bad, @Dagon... My english is not so good and i misunderstood the question. Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to get rid of the slashes:

```
$text = str_replace("\\'", "'", $text);
```

Comment: this is the ambulance at the bottom of the cliff, you should stop them being added in the first place